# Unable to Collapse Multiple Items

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, toggle

I am learning how to use bootstrap to make an Expand/Collapse button. I have two items that can Expand/Collapse when clicked on and I also have a main Expand/Collapse for all items. The issue is when one item is expanded, and the other is not. The main Expand/Collapse button will close the first one but open the second one. How can I make the main button to Expand/Collapse whether the items are Expanded or not?

```
<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Expand/Collapse</button>

  <div class="card">  
    <div class="card-body">
      <button class="card-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse">Test</button>

      <div class="card-text" id="collapse">
      test
      </div>


      <button class="card-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse">
        <strong>Test2</strong>
      </button>

      <div class="card-text" id="collapse1">
     Beta2
      </div> 

    </div>
  </div>
```

below is the code for the main button:

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){
    $(".card-text").collapse('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [answered for Bootstrap 3.x here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538051/bootstrap-accordion-expand-collapse-all-not-functioning-properly), and the concept is still the same, the individual collapse elements have there own Expand/Collapse state, and all the button is doing right now is toggling the state of each button.

**The expand/collapse all button must track the current state of "Expand" or "Collapse" *ALL***.

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){

    if ($(this).data("closedAll")) {
        $(".collapse").collapse("show");
    }
    else {
        $(".collapse").collapse("hide");
    }

    // toggle state and remember it
    $(this).data("closedAll",!$(this).data("closedAll")); 
});

// init with all closed
$(".btn-primary").data("closedAll",true);
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/i5h1tBmTaa

Answer (score 0):

I did not 100% understand your question, But I wrote a snippet on jsfiddle to work accordingly as I understood.

The best way is to use conditional statements to check whether those components are collapsed or not. Based on that we can use collapse methods which are mentioned in the [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#collapseExample)

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <button id="main-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb5">Expand/Collapse</button>

  <div class="card">  
    <div class="card-body">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info d-block m-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Demo 01</button>
    <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info d-block m-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Demo 02</button>
    <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>

  </div> 
</div>
```

This is the jQuery part

```
$('.collapse').collapse();


$('#main-button').on('click',function(){
  let demo1 = $('#demo1');
  let demo2 = $('#demo2');

  if(demo1.hasClass('show') && demo2.hasClass('show')){
    demo1.collapse('hide');
    demo2.collapse('hide');
  }

  if((demo1.hasClass('show') === false) && (demo2.hasClass('show') === false) ){
    demo1.collapse('show');
    demo2.collapse('show');
  }

  if((demo1.hasClass('show') === false) && (demo2.hasClass('show') === true) ){
    demo2.collapse('hide');
  }

  if((demo1.hasClass('show') === true) && (demo2.hasClass('show') === false) ){
    demo1.collapse('hide');
  }


});
```

I wrote it in js fiddle, click [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dmcshehan/oypL9m6d/38/) to see it.